Cannot read mongoDB object from clickhouse mongodb function
While using mongodb function in clickhouse ref - https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/table-functions/mongodb, to read a collection in the following format
{
  _id: ObjectId('63aaa3c9972e2b2adee20408'),
  bag_id: 403747,
  delivery_slot: {
    slot: 'By 07:00 AM',
    upper_bound: '2023-01-04T07:50:27+00:00',
    lower_bound: '2023-01-02T07:50:27+00:00',
    date: '2023-01-04T07:50:27+00:00',
    type: 'order_window'
  },
  display_name: 'Bag'
}

The query I am using is of the format
SELECT 
    bag_id, 
    display_name,
   delivery_slot.date
FROM mongodb(
    '<IP>:<host>', 
    'db', 
    'collection',
    'username',
    'password',
    'bag_id UInt64, 
     display_name String, 
     delivery_slot Nested( slot String, lower_bound String, upper_bound String, date String, type String)', 
    'connectTimeoutMS=10000'
) 
LIMIT 100;

The result looks like this
bag_id|display_name|delivery_slot.date|

------+------------+------------------+

403747|Bag         |[]                |

403754|Bag         |[]                |

403755|Bag         |[]                |

403756|Bag         |[]                |

403757|Bag         |[]                |

403758|Bag         |[]                |

403759|Bag         |[]                |

Please help in suggesting a schema that i can use in the MongoDB function to read the data properly from MongoDB using clickhouse.
Expexted result
bag_id|display_name|delivery_slot.date|

------+------------+------------------+

403747|Bag         |2023-01-04T07:50:27+00:00              |

403754|Bag         |2023-01-04T07:50:27+00:00              |

403755|Bag         |2023-01-04T07:50:27+00:00                |

403756|Bag         |2023-01-04T07:50:27+00:00                |

403757|Bag         |2023-01-04T07:50:27+00:00                |

403758|Bag         |2023-01-04T07:50:27+00:00               |

403759|Bag         |2023-01-04T07:50:27+00:00               |

While the actual result I get is empty arrays in deliver_slot.date.

have you tried Map(String, String) ? Alternatively you could do the block as a string and then parse on the clickhouse side with JSON functions https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/json-functions


MongoDB Engine supports only non-nested data types.

Map(String,String) should work however - you can then cast downstream. Alternatively just treat as a string and then parse the SELECT using JSON functions.
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/json-functions

When using Map(), in the schema as "bag_id UInt64, display_name String, delivery_slot Map(String, String)" get the error Exception: Unsupported type Map(String, String). (UNKNOWN_TYPE) whereas using String and extracting it using  SELECT JSONExtractRaw(delivery_slot) as slot It gives error type mismatch, expected String, got type id = 3 for column delivery_slot: . Have tried casting as well, it does not work. Any other suggestions?

With String the issue is reading Object is that it always fails with type mismatch when printing the value in select.

I recall i opened an issue on this now https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/51929 Ill see if i can find a workaround

I have raised the same to Clickhouse, and that issue is marked as a bug here - https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/64097 In case anyone ends up here looking to solve a similar use case. It seems like this is currently a limitation in Clickhouse.
